# Given $\sum\limits_{i=1}^m(a_i+b_i)=c,$ what is the maximal value of the expression $\sum\limits_{i=1}^ma_ib_i?$

Tags: real-analysis, inequality, optimization

Given $2m$ non-negative numbers $\{a_i\}_{i=1}^m$ and $\{b_i\}_{i=1}^m$ with $\sum\limits_{i=1}^m(a_i+b_i)=c,$ what is the maximal possible value of the expression $\sum\limits_{i=1}^ma_ib_i?$

When $m=1$ then given $a_1+b_1=c,$ the maximal value of $a_1b_1$ is $c^2/4$. How can  that maximal value be calculated for the case $m>1$?

Comment: Do you know the method of Lagrange multipliers?

Comment: That will be $c^2/4$ too.

Comment: I don't think there will much change. Whatever the optimum is, you can, for all $i$, vary $a_i$ and $b_i$ while keeping their sum fixed. The product $a_ib_i$ is then maximized when $a_i=b_i$. So at the optimal point $a_i=b_i$ for all $i$. It sure looks like the maximum is attained by concentrating all the available mass to a single component.

Comment: Why nobody speak about rearrangement inequality ?

Comment: @Mister.Expandead: According to the rearrangement inequality it suffices to consider the case where both the $a_i$ and the $b_i$ are in increasing order. But I do not yet see how that simplifies the remaining calculation.

Comment: @MartinR I think we can start from the end of the  reasoning and next use rearrangement inequality  no ? Thanks for your interest !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We have
$$
\sum_{i=1}^m a_i b_i \le \frac 14 \sum_{i=1}^m (a_i + b_i)^2
\le \frac 14 \left( \sum_{i=1}^m (a_i + b_i)\right)^2 = \frac 14 c^2 \, .
$$
Equality holds (exactly) if $a_j = b_j = c/2$ for one index $j$ and all other $a_i, b_i$ are zero.

The first estimate is the inequality between geometric and arithmetic mean, and the second estimate is
$$
 c_1^2 + \ldots + c_m^2 \le (c_1 + \ldots + c_m)^2
$$
for non-negative real numbers, with equality if and only if all but one $c_i$ are zero.

Comment: You seem to have missed a $m$ somewhere. You can check with my answer.

Comment: $a_j=b_j=c/2m$ instead of $c/2$

Comment: @ShivTavker: That is not what I said. With $a_1=b_1=c/2$ and all other $a_i, b_i$ equal to zero you get the maximal value $c^2/4$, for arbitrary $m$. – I am fairly sure that my result is correct.

Comment: @MartinR What's the name of the second estimate? I'm actually curious about it :)

Comment: @JoseRamirez: I don't know if that has a name. The estimate just follows from expanding $(c_1 + \ldots + c_m)^2$ and then omitting all “mixed terms” $c_i c_j$. (You could also say that the function $c_1^2 + \ldots + c_n^2$ is convex on the domain $c_1 + \ldots + c_m = const$ and therefore attains its maximum at an extremal point :)